# Problem with jquery and IE 8 and later

Tags: java, jquery, internet-explorer

In Firefox work, but when load page in IE8 i get only blank page and source HTML-code available.

I delete

```
 <script src="/NewsManager/js/jquery.js"    
                type = "text/javascript"
    </script>
```

and all work without script.

NetBeans 6.7, ApacheTomcat, JSP

Comment: What errors do you get in the JS console? Do you have a link we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the closing `>` in second line:

```
<script src="/NewsManager/js/jquery.js"    
            type = "text/javascript"> <!-- close the opening script tag HERE -->
```

Try this:

```
<script src="/NewsManager/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="/NewsManager/js/jquery.js"    
                    type = "text/javascript"/>


fixed, but didn't help

Comment: @Ivan: Updated my answer, a _standalone_ should not be used for _script_ elements. also remove the blanks between type, =, and "text...

Comment: @Ivan: thanks, that many bugs in one row really indicate you should take a break :-)